# Swift Particular Closure Syntax

Tags: swift

In [this](https://github.com/palewar/CS193P/blob/master/Psychologist%20VCL/Psychologist/HappinessViewController.swift) application there is the statement:

```
var instanceCount = { globalHappinessInstanceCount++ }()
```

In trying to understand the above statement I have found that, as far as I've tested, the statement below achieves the same result:

```
var instanceCount = globalHappinessInstanceCount++
```

Q1.  What's the first statement achieving that the second doesn't?

Q2.  Are the () braces following the closure expression signifying an empty tuple, initialiser syntax, ... or what?  I.e how should one read the first statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1. What's the first statement achieving that the second doesn't?

AFAIK it just creates an unnecessary closure which doesn't add any value...

> Q2. Are the () braces following the closure expression signifying an empty tuple, initialiser syntax, ... or what? I.e how should one read the first statement?

It is method call. Just like

```
let foo = { globalHappinessInstanceCount++ }
foo()
```

---

Update:

I just read the code in your link, in the context of class scope, it is different.

```
class HappinessViewController
{
    var instanceCount = { globalHappinessInstanceCount++ }()
}
```

defines a property `instanceCount: Int` that get assigned value of `globalHappinessInstanceCount++`

It is not that much different than `var instanceCount = globalHappinessInstanceCount++`

However in Swift 3, `++` operator will be removed, which you may want to change it to `globalHappinessInstanceCount += 1`. But the issue is the result type of `+=` operator is `Void` instead `Int`. So you have to write it like

```
class HappinessViewController
{
    var instanceCount: Int = {
        let instanceCount = globalInstanceCount
        globalInstanceCount += 1
        return instanceCount
    }()
}
```

Comment: So even in the class scope is the first statement still using an unnecessary closure?

Comment: I think we need    defer {globalHappinessInstanceCount += 1} because ++ is postfix.

Comment: So now for Swift 3 deprecated ++  we've needed to add an :Int type specification, a defer block and a return statement.  Might this just be sufficient reason to pressure for a reversal of the deprecated operator decision?

Comment: The closure doesn't make any difference during my brief testing. I think in Swift 3 you still have custom operator, which you can should be able to reimplement `++` operator?

Comment: It might be more readable to use `let instanceCount = globalInstanceCount; globalInstanceCount += 1; return instanceCount` instead of addition and then subtraction.